# Switch off CUDA in PyTorch without uninstalling

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch, and by mistake I have installed PyTorch with CUDA version 10.2. In reality, I do not have CUDA available in my system.
So when I compile my program, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torch_cluster were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA version 10.2 and torch_cluster has CUDA version 0.0. Please reinstall the torch_cluster that matches your PyTorch install.`

I would like to switch my CUDA in PyTorch to CPU (or CUDA 0.0, as far as I understood, it is equivalent term). So is it possible to do without reinstallation of the PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to resolve your dependencies (`pytorch_cluster` might automatically set GPU to `true`, maybe you could try to catch this error during import, but this is pointless and terrible thing to do as some parts of libraries might not be initialized or not work at all due to aforementioned). Recreate the environment or `pip uninstall` both packages and follow below (I assume `pip`, you can also go for `conda` (maybe with `pip` inside))

### CPU only

**I would advise against that, use CUDA if you can**. As mentioned, you can simply **not use `.to("cuda")` calls on your tensors/models**

Install PyTorch (as per [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)), via `pip` it would be:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Same for `pytorch_cluster` (I assume this is your dependency, link [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_cluster)):

```
pip install torch-cluster -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cpu.html
```

**Please notice the same `torch` version `1.7.0` in both commands**

### GPU

Almost the same (default is `CUDA==10.2`):

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cu102
```

And for `torch_cluster`:

```
pip install torch-cluster -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cu102.html
```

It **should** work with PyTorch `1.7.1` not `1.7.0` as above, but you can follow these steps just to be on the safe side.

Also [here](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-geometric.com/whl/index.html) are available pytorch-geometric versions you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Uninstall the pytorch

```
pip uninstall torch
```

Step2: Reinstall. Get one version you would like to install from [here](https://pytorch.org/)

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```